# How to delete a file whose owner is set to 777 by mistake on linux

Tags: linux, chown

Tried with a few things I could think of without success. Ideas? Thanks.

Comment: by mistake?? 777 already means anyone can modify the file already

Comment: Can you not delete it as root?  Is not 777 just a random user ID?

Comment: @danidee OP said the `owner` is set to 777.

Comment: is 777 not a permisson for anyone on the system to read write and execute?

Comment: What "few things" did you think of?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to delete the file if you run the remove command with sudo

```
sudo rm /path/to/file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's your server, you can just `sudo rm file`.

Comment: Please do **not** do -rf in this situation.  It will not help you and it could be a disaster.

Comment: The reason it could be a disaster is that if the file is a linke to a folder structure and you aren't aware of it, it will do a recursive delete.  You don't want to do `-rf` unless you explicitly want to recursively delete something.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to everyone. The answer is when all attempts to change owner of the file fail, check the owner of its parent directory :).

Answer (score -2):

`rm -rf filename` if you have the permission do delete the file

Otherwise:

`sudo chown user filename && rm -rf filename` where `user` is your username.

Comment: Please do not do -rf in this situation. It will not help you and it could be a disaster.

Comment: The reason it could be a disaster is that if the file is a linke to a folder structure and you aren't aware of it, it will do a recursive delete.  You don't want to do `-rf` unless you explicitly want to recursively delete something.